# Windows rasdial OR dotras? Which one is preferred for connecting and diconnecting

Tags: c#, windows, ras, dotras

I'm trying to code an automated VPN connection, i'm seeing codes getting a VPN connection connected/disconnected using both Rasdial.exe and DotRAS . Just wanted to make sure which one is preferred if i need my app to be run from Windows XP to Windows 10?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends on what it is you’re wanting to do with your application. RasDial.exe will let your application dial a connection but won’t give you much control outside of that.

DotRas grants you more control over the Win32 API but I haven’t yet updated the published version for Windows 10 support.

Also you may want to consider dropping Windows XP support as it is no longer supported by Microsoft and most new features that are cross OS compatible for VPN connections is in Windows 7 or higher (which is almost out of support by Microsoft).